# Why .closest(selector) returns more than one value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a part of my html. (it is written using ejs)

```
<div class="objAddDiv">
    <tr><td><button class="addObj">Do this action</button></td></tr>
    <table><div class="objects"></div></table>
</div>
```

I have several objAddDiv divs on this page. Each has the same structure inside of it. I use `.append()` to add more ejs to `.objects`. I am having a hard time adding to only the `.objects` div that is inside of the same div as the button. I tried doing the following

```
".addObj click": function(el, element){
    $(".addObj").closest(".objAddDiv").find(".objects").append(//my ejs utility here)
}
```

The problem is that  `$(".addObj").closest(".objAddDiv")` returns all `.objAddDiv` on the page. I have looked at [the jquery documentation for `.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and it says closest should only return one element. Is there a better way to do this? What am I doing wrong. (these are not my real class names btw)

Comment: Because you are using $(".addObj") so it will firstly match all this elements then return each closest .objects elements relative to each .addObj

Comment: @A.Wolff (face palm) is there a way around this?

Comment: ya use $(this) if it is inside click handler

Comment: first you need to get a reference to a single instance of `addObj` element... if you can some more info about the context where you are doing this we might be able to help you

Comment: @A.Wolff When I do that it returns the controller

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot controller? What does mean?

Comment: @A.Wolff I am using MVC. This is all being done from the javascript when I evaluate $(this) it returns the javascript context not the html context

Comment: In which context are you calling this code? I guess, it should be inside an handler (event)

Comment: @A.Wolff Hey I just figured it out when I was editing I needed to call it from the el I passed in thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer that I figured out (for anyone who comes next) I needed to use the element I passed into the function:

```
el.closest(".objAddDiv").find(".objects").append(//ejs append stuff)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are calling that method on every element with a class of 'addObj':

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

So you get the closest `objAddDiv` to each `addObj` element.

Assuming you are doing this inside the click event of the button use this to get the correct element:

```
$(this).closest(".objAddDiv").find(".objects").append(//my ejs utility here)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't provide the right information. What worked is below in my answer